# $Z$-boson decay into two neutrinos depends on the Dirac or Majorana nature of the neutrinos?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, majorana-fermions

The decay rate of the $Z$-boson into two active neutrinos $Z \rightarrow \nu \overline{\nu}$ can be calculated straightforwardly and I obtained the same as in the literature. However, I was wondering, why doesn't it depend on the nature of the neutrinos? If the neutrinos were Majorana particles, the $\nu$ and the $\overline{\nu}$ would be the same and they would be indistinguishable. This would introduce a factor of $\frac{1}{2!}$, when computing the decay rate. Since I have not seen this anywhere, I assume I understood something wrong, and I would appreciate it if someone could point it out.

Comment: A Majorana mass is what connects particles and antiparticles. What are the momenta of the neutrinos, and how does this compare to limits on the the neutrino mass?

Answer (score 2):

The factor $\tfrac{1}{2!}$ is correct. You need to take into account that, given the $Z-\bar\nu-\nu$ vertex operator, you can now contract both final state fermions with both $\bar\nu$ and $\nu$ operators. This will change things at the amplitude level, giving an extra factor two when you calculate the amplitude squared. This factor 2 cancels the $\tfrac{1}{2}$ you mention.